# Dropdown variable script

Tags: php, html

I have the following code:

```
echo "<td><textarea wrap='soft' class=tarea3  name='inston[]'>".$r['inston']."</textarea></td>\n";
```

I'd like to use that `inston` variable to associate with a dropdown list.  I have working code for the dropdown list:

```
  <tr><td class="tdt">

  <?php te('Hosting Server');?>:</td> <td title='Select server'>
   <select validate='required:true' class='mandatory' name='manufacturerid'>
   <option value=''>Select</option>
  <?php 
    foreach ($agents5 as $a) {
      $dbid=$a['id'];
      $atype=$a['label']; $s="";
      if (isset($manufacturerid) && $manufacturerid==$a['id']) $s=" SELECTED ";
      echo "<option $s value='$dbid' title='$dbid'>$atype</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
  ?>


  </td></tr>
```

and a sql query for the above mentioned dropdown script,

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM items where itemtypeid=32 OR itemtypeid=44 order by label";
$sth=db_execute($dbh,$sql);
while ($r=$sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) $agents5[$r['id']]=$r;
```

How can we use the code above to associate `inston` variable?

Comment: "associate inston variable" with what?

Comment: with the dropdown script(2nd script).thanks

Comment: Excuse me - I mean, associate it how?

Comment: What does this inston variable do? Does it need to be in the drop down? I dont get what youre asking.

Comment: inston will be the value of dropdown selection.thanks

Comment: Alright... With a dropdown form you need 2 elements.. A value (Usually an ID) and a Option. Saying that you need to associate a random variable (inston) is not giving us enough information. Is this inston a list? is it a single variable that needs to be added to the dropdown? Does it have a unique ID like the manufacturerid? If it's just something that needs to be added to the list why not include it in the variable that is already there? ($atype)

Comment: Thanks cory i think i'll use $atype as the variable that should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear and from what i understood, is suppose the answer to be this

First of all ,  use an  `id` for the `select` tag and `textarea` and use an `onChange` function like this:

```
<textarea wrap='soft' class=tarea3  name='inston[]' id='inston'>".$r['inston']."</textarea>
<select validate='required:true' class='mandatory' name='manufacturerid' id='manufacturerid' onChange='setInston()'>
```

and the use this javascript function :

```
function setInston() {
  var x = document.getElementById("manufacturerid").value;
  document.getElementById("inston").innerHTML= x+"&#10;";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aditya,|Appreciate your help.Following your code i came up with this
 echo "<td title='Select'>
    <select validate='required:true' class='mandatory' name='manufacturerid'>
    <option value=''>Select</option>\n";
 
 
      foreach ($agents5 as $a) {
       $dbid=$a['id'];
       $r['inston']=$a['label']; $s="";
       if (isset($manufacturerid) && $manufacturerid==$a['id']) $s=" SELECTED ";
 echo "<option $s value='$dbid' title='$dbid'>".$r['inston']."</option>\n";
 }
echo "<td></td>\n";|Its working fine i get my expected dropdown list ,but for some reason it doesn't post..any ideas??

Comment: I didn't get you @Carter , What are you trying to post ? and also where are you trying to post ?? 
Are you trying to get the value selected in the dropdown list in the textarea, or is it the reverse ??

Comment: Thanks again Aditya,All sorted. It wasn't posting because of a datatype error.Just fixed it.

Comment: then at least mark it as the answer